# How to Authenticate a URLRequest Using Alamofire with OAuth1

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, alamofire, oauth-1.0a

I am having a problem trying to Authenticate a request using alamofire and OAuth1 and I am using this library to do so:
https://github.com/phenemann/Authentication/
but I am not able to succeed if you know how to use alamofire with OAuth1.

Bellow is my progress till this moment

```
class HttpRestManager{
public static func sendRequest(url: String, authorizationType: AuthorizationType, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: [String: Any]?, headers: NSMutableDictionary, complition: @escaping (_ results: String?, _ errors: Error?, _ statusCode: Int?) -> Void){
    let preparedHeaders = prepareHeaders(headers: headers, authorizationType: authorizationType)
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
    manager.adapter = AuthorizationAdapter()
    manager.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: preparedHeaders).responseString { (response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let value):
            complition(value, nil, response.response?.statusCode)
        case .failure(let error):
            complition(nil, error, response.response?.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this is the adapter I am using:

```
class AuthorizationAdapter: RequestAdapter {
private let CONSUMER_KEY = "****";
private let CONSUMER_SECRET = "****";
private let TOKEN_ID = "****";
private let TOKEN_SECRET = "****";

func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    let oAuthMethod = AuthenticationMethod.oauth1(consumerKey: CONSUMER_KEY,
                                                  consumerSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                  accessKey: TOKEN_ID,
                                                  accessSecret: TOKEN_SECRET)
    let authorizer = Authenticator(method: oAuthMethod)
    let authorizedRequest = try? authorizer.signRequest(request: urlRequest)
    return authorizedRequest!
}
}
```

please note that I have the ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, TokenID and TokenSecret there is no CallBackUrl or anything I Just need to generate the "oauth_signiture" value, based on the request URL and it's parameters, I have generated it but the response I get is "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", and whenever I test the API on Postman it succeeds even though the generated header is similar to the one I generate, please help me or tell me what I am doing wrong, many thanks.